# Why am I getting error print() on closed filehandle in Perl

Tags: perl, input, output

I am trying to write output to one C file but I'm getting an error about `print() on closed filehandle`.

```
my $fileoutput="output.c";
open OUTFILE, "> $fileoutput" or die $!;
for my $i (keys%hash) {
    # grep for c file output and compare
    # with xml key print both key and values
    if (grep $_ eq $i,@c_result_array) {
        if (defined $hash{$i}) {
            my @values = $hash{$i};
            print OUTFILE $i . "=> @values";
            print OUTFILE "\n";
        }

        close OUTFILE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't close OUTFILE inside the loop...

Comment: am getting this error in for loop :"print() on closed filehandle OUTFILE at main.pl line 137 ,print() on closed filehandle OUTFILE at main.pl line 138."like repeatedly .

Comment: even after putting Outside the loop getting same error

Comment: There is really no need in general for a `close` on file handles as Perl will close them for you when the program terminates. If your output data is critical and you want to be sure that it has been written to disk then you can `close` the output filer handle, but you need to check the return status for this to be of any benefit. Alternatively, if you have a program that has a huge number of file handles then it is wasteful to leave them open once you are done with them

Answer (score 3):

You close the output file inside the `for` loop. By the second iteration, the file handle has been closed. You have to close the file once the loop has run to completion.

Also, bareword file handles have package scope which comes with all the disadvantages of global variables. Use lexical file handles.

Also, especially if the name of the file you are opening is coming from the outside, use the three argument form of open, and always include the name of the file in error messages.

Finally, presumably, `$hash{$i}` contains an array reference, so you have to dereference it if you are going to interpolate its contents into a string.

```
my $fileoutput = "output.c";
open my $OUTFILE, '>', $fileoutput
    or die "Failed to open '$fileoutput': $!";

for my $i (keys %hash) {
   #grep for c file output and compare with xml key print both key and values #
   if (grep $_ eq $i, @c_result_array) {
      if(defined $hash{$i}) {
            my @values = @{ $hash{$i} };
            print $OUTFILE "$i => @values\n";
       }
   }
}
close $OUTFILE
    or die "Failed to close '$fileoutput': $!";
```

Comment: @srikanth sorry my fault. See my updated answer. The close statement must be the last line of the code snipped.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation so it is consistent?  I tried twice but couldn't decide how you'd want it done.

Comment: Can I suggest: This answer would be improved if there were 3 arg open with lexical filehandles. 2 arg open works, but is generally bad style.

Comment: yes you are correct i accept . i am new to perl ,in many  books i saw like this only ; so plz tell me which is better style of writing ..thank you

Comment: i found that i was using bad style thank you i will make changes  source  http://perlmaven.com/open-files-in-the-old-way